# dynamic javascript loading

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dynamic-loading

I have some abstract question.
Lets say I have a website which uses 1000+ JS script files. (Not at once, but in the overall 1000+ JS scripts are needed if user goes through all existing flows).

I know that using RequireJS I could dynamically load whichever scripts I need, and that saves me a long time loading them all at once.
**But!**

In order for RequireJS to load the JS files, they need to be downloaded by the client.
So what happens is that the first time I open the web page, I download more than 1000 JS script files, which takes long time too!

I was wondering if there's any way for dynamic loading to also dynamic download them from remote.
I know that for this to work best, there must be some clever mechanism that will finish download them **before** something tries to use them, otherwise it'll slowdown things.

Anyway, I hope you understand my question, I want to avoid downloading 1000+ files on the first time I open the page. I'd like them to be downloaded on demand.

**I can't** make combine them to a single file like many web sites do.

Thanks for your help and discussion :)

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. Yes, RequireJS can load the scripts dynamically as you need them. That is literally the opposite of loading all 1000+ files the first time you open the page.

Comment: I think we're not in the same page, when you're saying RequireJS loads a script dynamically, do you mean that the script needs to be downloaded from the remote server and then loaded to be available for usage?

Comment: I think the point where your confusion comes is this: *"In order for RequireJS to load the JS files, they need to be downloaded by the client."* There is actually no difference between "RequireJS to load JS files" and "downloaded by the client" -- downloading *is* the way RequireJS loads the files. You're treating "downloading" and "loading" as separate things when they're actually the same thing. If you'd have to pre-load all files before RequireJS could "load" them it would make RequireJS completely unusable, don't you think?

Comment: I understand now, thanks. So I assume that every .js file that was downloaded was a required one.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're trying to achieve 'lazy loading'.
You can use this plugin for require:
https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy

Read more here:
http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/lazy-loading-javascript-with-requirejs/

The main idea here is that, instead of loading all the dependencies when the page loads, you provide a method for loading the necessary items, and you call that method when needed

For example: (load files after a user clicks a button)

```
$('#somebutton').on('click', loadFiles);

function loadFiles() {
    require(['every', 'javascript', 'dependency', 'for', 'other', 'screen'], 
    function(ev, js, dep, fr, othr, scrn){
            // Create the screen with your dependencies
    });
}
```